# Why is my command prompt getting stuck after I type ruby?

Tags: ruby, command-line

I am getting an error when trying to run Ruby on my Mac. I installed it using RVM. But when I type it in, it gets stuck on the command prompt, like its waiting. The same happens with the default. I have no idea why this is happening. Running 10.7.3. Any ideas?

Comment: It awaits some input, I suppose. If you need interactive ruby console, run `irb`.

Comment: tells me 1.9.3p125 etc. and its not waiting for input. But when I run irb, it works... I am confused

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *is* waiting, and it's waiting for input. The `ruby` command takes in input till it receives the `EOF` character, and then executes it. Typically you pass it a file to run or pipe to `stdin`.

Perhaps you're trying to run interactive Ruby (IRb)? In which case you should run `irb`.

Comment: Adding on: To send an EOF, use Ctl+D.

Comment: @Emily Yup! That's also a quicker way to exit IRb (among many, many other things) that typing "exit"/"quit"/etc.

Comment: Oh wow, I see. I thought in the past before I knew about ruby that it ran by calling the obvious ruby

Comment: Whats IRB by the way? Sorry, new to ruby. Is it like the command line in lisp?

Comment: @Andy Yes, I faced the same situation few days ago, when I tried ruby from console after several years.

Comment: Oh ok, gotcha @kirilloid much appreciated

Comment: @Andy As stated in my answer IRb stands for interactive Ruby. You can [read more about it in the pickaxe](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/irb.html).

Comment: IRB is an interactive ruby interpreter. You type in a line, and as soon as you hit return it's run and shows you the result. Running ruby is indeed done by calling `ruby` but it has to have something to run! It was waiting for you to type it in. You can do `ruby file.rb` to run a file, or `ruby -e "puts 'awesome'"` to run a little snippet of code.

Comment: I apologize for the stupid question! I assumed it worked like Lisp, which can load the file while in the interpreter. Though I must say, searching it on google did not make that answer readily available. Thanks again!